# how to write jasmine test case for angular js function

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine, testcase

I am using jasmine 2.0 for testing javascript functions.

```
$scope.onReturnDateChange=function(){
  if($scope.details.returndate){
    if($scope.details.id='Inquiry'||$scope.details.amount=''){
      return
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i could not able to write test cases in jasmine iam new to UI test cases

Comment: that's one of the easiest tests to write, look for `spyOn` and angular unit tests

Comment: what does this method do? what does it return? did you really meen to  assign values inside an `if` statement? this is not the best codeing...

Answer (score 0):

you have to use a spy for this purpose

First you need to add your controller

var $controller;

```
  beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_){
// The injector unwraps the underscores (_) from around the parameter names when matching
$controller = _$controller_;
}));
it('test',function(){
var $scope = {};
var controller = $controller('Controller_name', { $scope: $scope });
spyOn($scope,'onReturnDateChange')
$scope.onReturnDateChange();
expect();
})
```

Comment: for this condition iam unable to write test case  if($scope.details.id='Inquiry'||$scope.details.amount=''){
      return
    }